# How to Redirect a user if they manually refresh your webpage via f5 or browser?

Tags: javascript, php

I have lots of buttons on my webpage, when a button is clicked it refreshs the page which I need to happen to increase my click counter, is there a way to redirect the user to another page if they decide to refresh after already clicked a button, So if they manually hit f5 or browser refresh they get redirected? otherwise what happens is every manual refresh my click counter just keeps counting? In PHP or Javascript I've looked around and apparently this is impossible?

Comment: How secure does this need to be? There is a way, but anyone who knows what the Internet is will be able to hack it.

Comment: Hey Jake I guess it would have to be a little secure as the information will be used by people to help make choices, I guess a hacker could have fun by just ramping the clicks up.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can probably prevent f5 from refreshing by keydown event and event.preventDefault(), I'm pretty sure you can't prevent the user clicking the refresh button.

But both of those are irrelevant because a hacker can just send a HTTP request, which would increase your counter.

You probably want to have PHP code that checks the user's IP and only increases the counter once per IP address.

To read the user's IP address in PHP, use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

You could store the counter data into a database table, for example with 3 columns:

table name: `counters`

table fields:

```
counter_id - INT UNSIGNED AUTO-INCREMENT(AI)
ip_address - VARCHAR(45)
hit_count - INT UNSIGNED
```

Then you could run SQL queries from PHP, to check if the counter has already been increased for an IP address, or to increase the counter.

Comment: Yeah Mex that sounds great!, wouldn;'t have faintest clue about how to check the ip address and allow one click per visitor. If I have multiple buttons and counters that mean I would have apply this method for each counter and button, Do you have any script to get me started in the right direction? Im not the best Php scipter lol.

Comment: Thanks alot Mex, I'll play around with what you have given me, thanks again.